# Adding By default Invites in Google Hangout API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I wanted to add dynamic emails in Invite in Google API every time user clicks on

> Start A Hangout On Air

then there will be some  emails stored in a dynamic variable that should be joined in hangout session. Please help me figuring out how to do send a varible to the following code on click of hangout button.

- **gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div3', {
       'render': 'createhangout',
       'invites': [{ 'id' : 'manish8081@gmail.com', 'invite_type' : 'EMAIL' },
                   { 'id' : *dynamicVariable*, 'invite_type' : 'EMAIL' }],
       'hangout_type': 'onair',
       'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '1088903491951' }],
       'widget_size': 175
      });**

How can I call a function on click of HAngout on Air Button and passing a value in it  ??

Answer (score 0):

In order to use any variable you'd pass, you'll need to load an extension (likely of your own creation), to process the information. In fact, you may find you have more power by having the extension load a page on your PHP server that can process your variable for you and send the emails as needed.

[Here's the most important help I can provide](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started)!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with hangout on air.
Only hangout call (defaut) you can put: invite.

See this: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2459411?hl=en
"**How do I invite my friends before I broadcast**?
You'll be prompted to invite your friends or circles before you enter the Hangout On Air. Please note that you can't invite the public to join a Hangout on Air, but you can open the broadcast for public viewing. To make it available to the public, click Start broadcast from within the Hangout On Air window."

see too: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/j7dqmOZh-M4
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#hangout_button_parameters

Comment: This doesn't provide answer to the question. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. "mee too", "same problem" will not be treated as answer.